# Autocomplete not showing suggestions when i enter alphabets

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I work in siebel. Its jquery version is 1.7.2. Jquery-ui version is 1.8.16.

Below is the code i use for autocomplete. I dont get suggestions when i enter alpha-numerical values. I get suggestions perfectly when I enter Numbers only.

```
$("#AutoSearchText").autocomplete().data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    console.log("inside render item");
    return $("<li>").data("item.autocomplete", item).append("<a><strong>Account Num:- " + item.FINSAcc + "</strong>" + "<br>" + "<strong>VIN:- " + item.VIN + "</strong>" + "<br>" + "<strong>SSN:- " + item.SSN + "</strong>" + "<br>" + "<strong>Contact:- " + item.Contact + "</strong></a>").appendTo(ul);
};
```

and triggering it through

```
 $("#AutoSearchText").autocomplete("option", "source", attr);
```

attr contains the source elements as objects

When I saw the html code when I entered alpha-numerical values, I saw that the ul element had its display attribute changed to none

```
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="ui-menu-7" role="menu" tabindex="0" style="z-index: 1; display: none; top: 26px; left: 599px; width: 235px;" aria-activedescendant="ui-menu-7-1">
```

Please let me know what am i doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

Sorry.

The "attr" variable that i was using as the source for autocomplete had the following structure

```
Contact: "NANCY H JOSLIN"
Acc: "00102400004470001"
SSN: "436086515"
label: "00102400004470001436086515"
```

when I entered "Acc" or "SSN" value I got the suggestion. But when i entered contact value, it didn't suggest.
The reason being "contact" value wasn't appended to "label". Now I have appended and got the autocomplete suggestion. It looks like below

```
Contact: "NANCY H JOSLIN"
Acc: "00102400004470001"
SSN: "436086515"
label: "00102400004470001436086515NANCY H JOSLIN"
```

Hope this helps someone